# Как возвращать значение из потока внутри генератора, который является обёрткой для другого генератора

Tags: python, многопоточность

Предлагаю сначала взглянуть на неудачный код:

```
from threading import Thread
from typing import Generator

class MyClass:
    @staticmethod
    def wrapped_generator(generator: Generator, updating_delay: float):
        data = 0

        def thread_function(gen: Generator, delay: float):
            global data
            while True:
                data = next(gen)
                time.sleep(delay)

        thread = Thread(target=thread_function, args=[generator, updating_delay], daemon=True)
        thread.start()

        while True:
            yield data
```

Мне нужен генератор-обёртка возвращающий значение, которое независимо обновляется в отдельном потоке.

Это нужно для идентичного подхода. У меня в проекте есть два типа значений: значения, которые я получаю по запросу и значения, которые обновляются независимо, и я должен получать "циферки", которое есть в данный момент.

Пользователь должен один раз указать тип значения, а потом пользоваться генератором забыв о реализации.
Поэтому я сначала создаю генераторы, а потом оборачиваю их в зависимости от типа.

Проблема возникла в том, чтобы получить значение из потока `thread_function`. Реализовав первое, что пришло в голову, получилось это.

```
>>> def my_gen():
...     a = 0
...     while True:
...         a += 1
...         yield a
        
>>> wrap_gen = MyClass.wrapped_generator(my_gen(), 1)
>>> next(wrap_gen)
0
>>> next(wrap_gen)
0
>>> data
5
>>> data
8
>>> next(wrap_gen)
0
```

Python создал глобальную переменную `data` в модуле и поток её обновляет, не беря во внимание локальную `data` генератора `wrapped_generator`.

Я ещё много каких фишек не знаю в Python, поэтому прошу подсказать, как реализовать задуманное?

Comment: `global data` → `nonlocal data`

Comment: Однако весь код в целом какой-то странный. Зачем поток создаётся внутри генератора? Что мешает просто создать поток и просто читать значение глобальной переменной, зачем здесь генератор вообще?

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо за ответ. В основном потому-что код выдернут из контекста. Все эти объекты генераторы будут доступны из методов класса и их будет неограниченное количество. При этом генераторы получают значение из объектов ввода-вывода, а выбрал я их из-за того, что они сохраняют состояние функции, без необходимости явно выделять память под адреса и различные настройки, от куда я реально получаю значения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо andreymal за ответ! Работает, как ожидается.

`global data` → `nonlocal data`

Comment: вы тогда уж пометьте ответ как общий.

Comment: @strawdog если автор комментария не захотел публиковать ответ, то таких обязательств перед ним нет.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ никто не говорит об обязательствах. речь о здравом смысле и справедливости.

Comment: @strawdog есть [разные точки зрения](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3061/176217) на это.

Comment: @strawdog, не вижу в окне исправления ответа галочки/пометки "общий"...

Comment: @αλεχολυτ я что-то вас понять не могу. если есть разные "точки зрения на это", то моя точка зрения может быть одной из них?

Comment: @Opekator нажмите [edit], справа внизу от поля редактирования будет чекбокс "Общий". Если уж очень хочется сделать ответ общим.

Comment: @strawdog может, а почему вы решили, что не может?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ нет чекбокса. Никаких чекбоксов вообще нет. Снизу поля редактирования только предпросмотр, описание, Сохранить изменения, отмена, ну и эти комментарии. Может из-за того, что это ответ на собственный вопрос?

Comment: @Opekator понятно, в чём дело. [Нужно 10 реп заработать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki). Я сейчас плюсану, проверь ещё раз.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ готово!